# Integrating WSO2 API Manager 2.1.0 with Azure AD

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, wso2-api-manager

We have requirement to configure Azure AD as a 3rd party key manager in WSO2 API gateway 2.1.0. Is there any reference available for the key manager client implementation with azure AD?

The scenario is that a mobile app will use Azure AD for authentication. Azure AD returns a token. Mobile app uses this token for API invocation via WSO2 API gateway. As per my understanding, this can be handled by configuring Azure AD as key manager in WSO2 API mananger.

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, the WOS2 API Manager used **Key Manager** to handle all clients, security and access token-related operations.

To integrate WOS2 API Manager with Azure AD, we need to implement the **Key Manager** ourselves. Then we can follow this [document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+a+Third-Party+Key+Manager) to configure the Third-Party Key Manager.

See the [WSO2 default Key Manager implementation](https://docs.wso2.com/download/attachments/57743353/AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java?version=3&modificationDate=1487913243000&api=v2) for a sample Key Manager implementation.

And here is the helpful documents about integrating application with Azure AD:

[Integrating applications with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications)